# System.out.write() not properly writing out certain bytes

Tags: eclipse

A buddy and me are doing an assignment which involves writing out bytes to a file. Normally we'd use something like a `FileOutputStream` but this assignment explicitly asks us to write out the data (which is, in this case, in bytes) to standard out. Unfortunately it's not working as expected.

For example, writing this code:

```
System.out.write(144); // write the byte 0x90, which is 144 as an int
System.out.flush();
```

...actually writes to standard out the byte corresponding to 63 as an integer, rather than 144.

We didn't seem to come across this issue when using a FileOutputStream, but as I said earlier, the assignment wants us to write to standard out. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe it has related to the console encoding. So redirect the execution of your program to a file a open it with an hex editor and see the results

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.write(144)` on your console ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html

Comment: maybe this could be useful? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)

Comment: How did you establish that it *actually writes to standard out the byte corresponding to 63 as an integer*? Please include relevant console logs or whatever other evidence you have.

Comment: Oddly enough, when trying this in Eclipse (and in the Eclipse settings, routing the output of the program to a txt file), if I examine it with a hex editor, it is 0x3F. However, when testing with Cygwin or command prompt, it's 0x90 as expected. But something is still odd, and that is earlier today I used cmd prompt to test our program and the bytes still weren't correct. I will try and provide updates as I do more testing...

Comment: You're mistaken. It's as simple as that. Recheck your observations. If FileOutputStream couldn't write a byte accurately very little would work, starting with the Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I was also surprised when I saw in the Eclipse console the character 0x3F (63) instead of 0x90. As suggested by Miguel Prz, the problem is related with the console encoding.
By default, it is set on cp1252 which seems to convert 0x90 to 0x3F. The best you can do is to set ISO-8859-1 and to redirect to a file (see screenshot).
The console try to display the characters as well, but when I copy-paste to a Hex editor I don't get the correct result.

**However, in this specific case I recommand to launch your program from a Windows or a Linux console and to redirect the output to a file**. So you avoid any encoding transformation and you write binary data directly to a file. ISO-8859-1 has worked for 0x90 but can give problems with other characters. Moreover, it makes little sense to display all the bytes (0x00 to 0xFF) in the standard output (Eclipse console or whatever).

[image]